# Oneliner to get the command which started a process on a certain port

Tags: networking, command-line, text-processing, process, netstat

I would need a one-line command which, given a port number, returns information on the command which started the process running on that port.

Usually, I get this information by running a [`sudo netstat`](https://protechnotes.com/checking-ports-linux-with-netstat/)

```
sudo netstat -antpv | grep PORT_NUMBER
```

which returns the `PID_NUMBER` on the 4th column, after the column character (`:`), and then I use the `PID_NUMBER` as input for a [`ps aux`](https://superuser.com/a/117921/1132403)

```
ps aux | grep PID_NUMBER
```

which returns information on the "starting command" on 11th column.

e.g.

```
# use the port number to get the process id
my_machine:~$ sudo netstat -antpv | grep 30001
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:30001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      616/python

# use the process id to get info on the command which started the process
my_machine:~$ ps aux | grep 616    
my_user       616  0.8  0.5 220112 89596 ?        S    01:10   6:59 /usr/bin/python my_program.py --log=INFO
```

Is it possible to get to this information with a one-line command?

e.g.

```
my_machine:~$ ps aux | grep get_only_the_number_after_the_column_character_in_the_4th_column_of(sudo netstat -antpv | grep PORT_NUMBER)

/usr/bin/python my_program.py --log=INFO
```

### Update

I am almost doing it.

I get what I want with

```
my_machine ~$ ps aux | awk '{if ($2 == "616") print $0;}'

my_user       616  0.7  0.5 220112 89596 ?        S    01:10   8:11 /usr/bin/python my_program.py --log=INFO
```

but it does not work when I try to save the PID in a bash variable and then pass it to awk

```
my_machine:~$ mypid=$(sudo lsof -ti :30001)
my_machine:~$ echo $mypid 
616

my_machine:~$ ps aux | awk '{if ($2 == "$mypid") print $0;}'
my_machine:~$

my_machine:~$ ps aux | awk -v mypid="$mypid" '{if ($2 == "mypid") print $0;}'
my_machine:~$

my_machine:~$ ps aux | awk -v mypid="616" '{if ($2 == "mypid") print $0;}'
my_machine:~$
```

Comment: :-) Do you mean `ps aux | awk -v mypid="$mypid" '{if ($2 == mypid) print $0;}'`

Comment: Please see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218753/how-to-pass-variables-to-awk-command-with-conditions

Comment: thaks for the syntax correction. It eems it does not work anyway :( see the question updates

Comment: `mypid` and not `"mypid"` … don’t quote the variable inside awk or it will not be expanded to its value and will be treated as a literal string instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are simpler straight foreword methods of getting the PID of a process that uses a certain port ... Like e.g. [`lsof`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/lsof.8.html) when used with the options `-i`(*which selects the listing of files any of whose Internet address matches the address specified - e.g. `:PORT_NUMBER`*) and `-t`(*which specifies that `lsof` should produce terse output with process identifiers only and no header - e.g., so that the output may be piped to `kill`*) like so:

```
sudo lsof -ti :30001
```

That you can use to feed the process ID to another command ... e.g. you can get what you want with:

```
ps -h -p $(sudo lsof -ti :30001) -o command
```

Or format the output as you wish like for example:

```
ps -h -p $(sudo lsof -ti :30001) -o user,pid,cpu,vsz,rss,tty,stat,start,time,command
```

You can further tune the options to get what you need ... Please have a look at [`man ps`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ps.1.html).

---

Also, you might find the [`ss`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/ss.8.html) command useful ... e.g. You might be able to get more information that you need in one step like so:

```
sudo ss -eaptn 'sport = :30001'
```

You can as well tune the options to get what you need ... Please have a look at [`man ss`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/ss.8.html).

Comment: `ps -h -p $(sudo lsof -ti :PORT_NUMBER) -o command` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!