# How to find out the program from iptables log

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, ipv6, ping

Testing the ping on ubuntu 22.04:

```
Host A IPv6: 1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111
Host B IPv6: 2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222
```

**Host A:**

Now execute a ping from Host A with the following bash command:

```
root@host_a:~# ping -6 2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222
```

**Host B:**

**The iptables dropped some packets and log it to the file:**

> Dec  7 18:21:52 host_b kernel: [  988.996335] dropped output: IN=
> OUT=ens33 SRC=192.168.1.1 DST=192.168.2.1 LEN=83 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00
> TTL=64 ID=52289 PROTO=UDP SPT=41151 DPT=53 LEN=63 UID=113 GID=118
>
> Dec  7 18:21:52 host_b kernel: [  988.998359] dropped output: IN=
> OUT=ens33 SRC=2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222
> DST=1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255
> FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=136 CODE=0
>
> Dec  7 18:21:53 host_b kernel: [  990.001075] dropped output: IN=
> OUT=ens33 SRC=2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222:2222
> DST=1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111:1111 LEN=72 TC=0 HOPLIMIT=255
> FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=136 CODE=0

**From the `first log line`, there is a `UID` and `GID` info:**

```
UID=113 GID=118
```

We can find the user by using this method:

```
root@host_b:~# cat /etc/passwd | grep 113
```

But for the `2nd` and `3rd` lines there is no any `UID` or `GID` in the log.

**Question:**

How to find out which program is sending out the following network packets?

```
PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=136 CODE=0
```

**Note:** Based on the iptables log, this "Unknown" program accepts incoming ICMPv6 packets and then send out outgoing ICMPv6 packets, but iptables can't log the UID and GID of that "Unknown" program when the packet is drooped by rule.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1442143/968501

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [Neighbour Discovery Protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbor_Discovery_Protocol) The blocked ICMP messages belong to the ipv6 Stack. Blocking them is not a good idea. The Stack in part of the kernel, no user process. There is no UID /GID of an user prosess.